# When implementing a custom Iterator with boost::iterator_adapter, can I use the same class for mutable and const Iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

I've a class that owns a `std::vector` and should provide `begin()`, `end()`, `cbegin()` and `cend()` methods. Since I don't want to expose implementation details, i.e. that I use a `std::vector`, I must have my own Iterator. As I understood, this is what [`boost::iterator_adapter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html#tutorial-example) is for: It takes some iterator and wraps it up within a new Iterator type -> my `std::vector<T>::iterator` becomes then `MyClass::iterator`.

First of all, is my understanding of boost::iterator_adapter correct and second can I avoid having to write a second const_iterator and instead e.g. typedef it (`using const_iterator = const iterator`)?

```
    class MyClass {
    public:
        iterator begin();
        // ...
    private:
        using container_t = std::vector;
        container_t<int> container;
    }

    class MyClass::iterator
      : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
            MyClass::iterator                     // Derived
          , container_t<int>::iterator            // Base
          , boost::use_default                    // Value
          , boost::random_access_traversal_tag >  // CategoryOrTraversal
    {
     public:
        iterator()
          : iterator::iterator_adaptor_() {}
        explicit iterator(const iterator::iterator_adaptor_::base_type& p)
          : iterator::iterator_adaptor_(p) {}
     private:
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    };
```

this might not compile.

Comment: What are you hiding by wrapping the iterator, which isn't hidden if u just forward  "begin(), end(), cbegin() and cend()"? I don't get it.

If performance doesn't matter here, they easiest and most flexible way is probably just an any_iterator

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use something like: `using const_iterator = const iterator`.

A `const_iterator` works like a `T const *`. A `const iterator` works like a `T * const`.

That is, what you want is an iterator that can be modified to point to other objects, but provides read-only access to those objects. What `const iterator` will give you is, instead, an iterator that can't itself be modified, but gives read/write access to the object to which it refers.